# Acquiring aws cross account iam role locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

I'm new to aws and facing problem for iam role.I'm doing cross account role. Say in Account x ,created role for Account Y togive permission to read from kinesis Streams.

I want to connect to Account Y to fetch streams from Account X locally using java SDK(i'm not launching EC2 instance on Account Y). So is their any way to do that?

I understand that if i run the application on EC2 instance on Account Y, I will be able to fectch it, but i don't want to fetch it by using EC2.

```
    AWS doc mentions in 
    https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/config-vars.html

    # In ~/.aws/credentials:
    [development]
    aws_access_key_id=foo
    aws_secret_access_key=bar 

    # In ~/.aws/config
    [profile crossaccount]
    role_arn=arn:aws:iam:...
    source_profile=development
```

Is it related to that?  Here i think crossaccount is the role created in account x to give access to account y.

```
Which aws api should I call to fetch the streams?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Account access in AWS has a specific protocol you'll need to follow. As you created an IAM Role in account X which has been given access to resources in account Y, account Y will also need to grant that role permission to perform `STS:AssumeRole`.

Once this part of setup is complete you should be good to go.
Read more about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html)

To use the AWS SDK for Java, create a service object for the `STS` service and perform an `AssumeRole` invocation. If you supply this with the right credentials, the result of that will be a valid pair of credentials that have access to account Y's resources.

Read more about using Assume Role in Java [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/delegating-api-access-to-aws-services-using-iam-roles/).

Comment: thanks Tom. So,  ~/.aws/credentials  and  ~/.aws/config will be used for the loading credentials(access key and id) and cross account role arn respectively?